# Search with predicate builder in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, predicate

Below is my method of searching using predicate builder there is no error showing in visual studio but the problem is that the below code is not executing.

```
public JsonResult GetSearchedGraph(string searchItem, string itemTypeEnum)
        {

            var pre = PredicateBuilder.True<Graph>();
           pre.And(m => m.isHidden == false && m.ItemType!="FOLDER");
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchItem))
           {
               pre.And(m => m.GraphItemTitle.ToUpper().Contains(searchItem.ToUpper()));
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(itemTypeEnum))
            {
                pre.And(m => m.ItemType == itemTypeEnum);
            }

            var searchGraph = from m in db.Graphs.AsQueryable() select m;
           searchGraph = db.Graphs.Where(pre);

           return Json(searchGraph.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I am not getting any search result by using this method what it is wrong with this code?

Comment: What do you mean by not executing? It crash without exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, you just have to do correct assignments.

because `pre.And()` doesn't impact `pre`

```
var pre = PredicateBuilder.True<Graph>();
//assign result of pre.And(xxx) to pre
pre = pre.And(m => m.isHidden == false && m.ItemType!="FOLDER");
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchItem))
{
     //same
     pre = pre.And(m => m.GraphItemTitle.ToUpper().Contains(searchItem.ToUpper()));
}
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(itemTypeEnum))
{
    //same
    pre = pre.And(m => m.ItemType == itemTypeEnum);
}
```